# GQL query help - How can I write a query with where clause in GQL ? I am using google appengine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have three records in a table 
example:

```
*Usernames*        *email*                *city*
Nick            nick@example.com        London
Vikky           vicky@example.com       Paris
Lisa            lisa@example.com        Sydney
```

Now I want to get specific record keeping email ID as a key ,

SQL query may be like this

```
select * from table1 where email = "vicky@example.com"
```

What is the equivalent GQL query for the above ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email = 'vicky@example.com'
```

should work fine in GQL.

See here for more information
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

Comment: hi ... it works if I query like this

 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE email = 'vicky@example.com'