# GQL basic query in Datastore Viewer console returns "No results in Empty namespace."

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I am running into a very basic problem of querying my data from the Datastore Viewer console based on a simple `WHERE <column> = 'xxx'` type query.

Here is a snapshot of my dummy data:

[image]

---

From what I understand, I should be able to query for that record based on the "email" field, or any other field, using `SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = 'a'`. But that returns "No results in Empty namespace." as can be seen below:

[image]

---

I don't see what is different to the situation in this related question:

- [GQL query help - How can I write a query with where clause in GQL ? I am using google appengine datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660057/gql-query-help-how-can-i-write-a-query-with-where-clause-in-gql-i-am-using-g?rq=1)

I have examined that record in the Entity editor, and can confirm that the value of the email field is "a", without any extra hidden spaces:

[image]

---

### Update

[Mihail suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143710/383414) that I need to create an index for this query.

Following the [Java Datastore Index Configuration docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig), I created the file `datastore-indexes.xml` in /war/WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="false">
    <datastore-index kind="User" ancestor="false">
        <property name="email" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

I was unable to deploy my project because it did not allow this index to be uploaded. The error message I got was:

> Creating a composite index failed for entity_type: "User"ancestor:
>   falseProperty {  name: "email"  direction: 1}: This index:entity_type:
>   "User"ancestor: falseProperty {  name: "email"  direction: 1}is not
>   necessary, since single-property indicies are built in. Please remove
>   it from your index file and upgrade to the latest version of the SDK,
>   if you haven't already.

Comment: Is the email property indexed? It will work just like you are describing when the property is not indexed.

Comment: @MihailR It does indeed look like an index problem... but for my personal curiosity, why wouldn't the error be "index needed" as it normally is in these cases?

Comment: Assuming you are using NDB (or any other Datastore library) - that's what's taking care of the "Index needed" exception. Datastore itself doesn't. You can even misspell property name (i.e. `email123` instead of `email`) and still won't get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `email` property is not indexed and you can't do any queries on unindexed properties, even as simple as this one, because if you had, say million users, this query would have to fetch all million entities to find the ones you need.

All you need to do is make the `email` property indexed but note that it will not take care of past entities. You are going to need to re-save all past entities in order for the new index to be applied.

**To make a property indexed**:

- In Objectify the `@Index` annotation needs to be added to the property. [More details here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Defining_Indexes).
- If using low-level Java Datastore API make sure to define the property with `setProperty()` and not with `setUnindexedProperty()`. [More details here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Unindexed_properties).
- If using Python's NDB, make sure `indexed` attribute is not set to `False` since most properties are indexed by default. [More details here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options).

Comment: How are you making the property indexed?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new index manually (you only need them when doing more complex queries with sorting) just make sure the property is indexed. How is the `email` property defined? Sorry but I am not very familiar with Java on GAE but looking at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Unindexed_properties is there any chance that you defined the `email` property with `setUnindexedProperty()` instead of `setProperty`?

Comment: As per previous comment, I was using Objectify, and had not indexed the  fields. Thanks for leading the way.